# Function that finds value and order which is value bigger than threshold in other array values

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I have an array like below.

```
a[125,256,258,259,276,257]
```

I am trying to find the array order number if there is any difference bigger than Threshold(for e.q 10) in array values.

In the above case ;

```
a[**125**,256,258,259,**276**,257]
```

`a[0]`: out of the threshold

`a[4]`: out of the threshold

Is there any easy way to find it in C code?

Comment: So we ll consider the majority of numbers which are close to each other? And finding the differences according to threshold?

Comment: don't need to find the difference, only need to find which one is out of threshold.

Comment: Okey threshold but according to what ? What is our reference ?

Comment: as you mentioned, reference is the majority of numbers which are close to each other

Comment: if the difference is bigger than 10, it will out of order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach:** You can draw a circle in your mind. The radius of this circle is threshold and  each element is a center. And determine if a circle consists less number of element comparing the others.

You can use these steps:

- Define threshold
- Check the differences of each element with the other one
- Count the elements whose differences is less than threshold and count them
- If there is 1 or less element this element is alone so out of threshold.

Here is the code and result:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int a[6] = {125,256,258,259,276,257};

    int threshold = 10;
    for(int i=0; i<6;i++)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<6;j++)
            counter += abs(a[j]-a[i])<=threshold?1:0;

        if(counter<2)
            printf("Detected out of threshold:  %d\n",a[i]);

        counter = 0;

    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Detected out of threshold:  125
Detected out of threshold:  276
```